# При вызове метода выбивает ошибку связанную с 'color'

Tags: javascript, объекты

```
var house = {
  windows: 'red',
  doors: 'green',

  paintWindows: function(color) {
    this.windows = color;
  }
};
```

при вызове:

```
house.paintWindows(blue);
```

Выбивает:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: blue is not defined at :1:20

Comment: Я надеюсь вы не предлагаете нам сидеть/стоять/прыгать и догадываться какую именно ошибку выбивает? Или подбирать как вызывать метод, чтоб её вызвать

Comment: Прошу прощения, при вызове: house.paintWindows(blue);
Выбивает: Uncaught ReferenceError: blue is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:20

Comment: все правильно. надо передавать строку в метод, а вы передаете неизвестную переменную

Comment: `blue` -> `"blue"`

Comment: спасибо не учёл

Comment: К объекту `house` это никакого отношения не имеет. Попробуйте: `console.log(blue);`